Link to the Mars Exploration Rover mission updates archive
Would anyone know where I can find the (archived) mission updates for the Mars Exploration Rover missions?
I remember NASA / JPL used to post mission updates every few sols but unfortunately, I can't find the link anymore. Does anyone know where I can find them? They're still doing it for MSL and M2020, but nothing was found on the MER webpage. Thanks

Are you sure it was NASA? https://www.planetary.org/articles/mer-update

Yeah I'm sure! It was a set of journal entries written by mission operations folks at JPL. I'll take a look at internet archives.

For some reason, NASA appears to have removed all MER mission updates with the refactoring of its websites a few years ago. I found them in internet archives using wayback machine.
For instance, here are the Opportunity updates as of July 2017: https://web.archive.org/web/20170705074735/https://mars.nasa.gov/mer/mission/status_opportunity.html
